# How does Vue implement the double curlys/mustache syntax?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

##### How does a frameworks like Vue implement their own custom syntaxes within an HTML document?

So I want to create a template engine, consequently I need to know how to implement my own custom syntax. I thought that an easy one would be the double curlys that can be used in **Vue**. Example of curlys:

`<h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>`

My first thought was to use `String.prototype.replaceAll(regex, string); but I got stuck at the regex I would use. In fact thinking about it now, I probably need a dynamic regular expression maybe?

```
    p.replaceAll(/\{\{()\}\}/g, '<p>{{embeddedVar}}</p>')
```

The other option I considered was a parser, or a lexer, but I didn't even know where to start. I built them in school in C++. I thought maybe NPM has one pre-built?

It seems like several developers have wrote their own custom template engine that has built-in support for the *double curly brackets*. I was thinking that maybe there is a common way that its being implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vue syntax is indeed not understood by the browser. the work is done by the Vue library that's imported in every Vue app.

The original markup (with the curly braces showing up) can even be seen for a split second when the page is loading, and this is because Vue hasn't loaded up all the way yet.